# Deﬁne a branch of $(z^2 − 1)^{1/2}$ which is analytic in the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, analyticity, branch-cuts

Hint: $z^2 − 1 = (z + 1)(z − 1)$.

I'm really struggling with this question. I understand that for this function to be analytic it has to be differentiable in some neighbourhood, but I have no idea where to start or even how to find/pick a branch.

Answer (score 3):

**First solution.** We use the following lemma

Lemma. *Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$ be an open region. If $a,b$ lie in the same connected component of $\,\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}\setminus\Omega$, then 
$$
f(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-b}
$$
possesses an analytic logarithm in $\Omega$.*

Using this lemma, let $g\in\mathcal H(\mathbb D)$, where $\mathbb D$ is the unit disk, the logarithm of $\,f(z)=\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}$, and set
$$
h(z)=(z+1)\exp\big(\tfrac{1}{2}g(z)\big).
$$
Then
$$
\big(h(z)\big)^2=(z+1)^2\exp\big(g(z)\big)=(z+1)^2\cdot\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}=z^2-1.
$$
*Proof of Lemma.* Observe that
$$
\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{z-a}-\frac{1}{z-b}.
$$
Hence, if $\gamma$ is a closed curve in $\Omega$, then 
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{f'}{f}=\mathrm{Ind}_\gamma(a)-\mathrm{Ind}_\gamma(b)=0,
$$
since $a,b$ lie in the same connected component of $\,\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}\setminus\Omega$.

Thus $\frac{f'}{f}$ possesses an holomorphic anti-derivative in $\Omega$, the analytic logarithm of $f$.

**Second solution.** Set $f(z)=g(z)h(z)$, where $g(z)=\sqrt{z-1}$, defined in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus [1,\infty)$ and $h(z)=\sqrt{z+1}$, defined in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus (-\infty,-1]$.

Now, how do we define $h(z)=\sqrt{z+1}$ in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus (-\infty,-1]$?

Every $z\in \mathbb C\smallsetminus (-\infty,-1]$ can be written UNIQUELY as $z=-1+r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}$, with $r>0$ and $\vartheta\in (-\pi,\pi)$. then show that the function 
$$
H(r,\vartheta)=r^{1/2}\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta/2},
$$
for $r>0$ and $\vartheta\in (-\pi,\pi)$. You can do it expressing Cauchy-Riemann equations with respect to $r$ and $\vartheta$ (See $(3)$ in this [paper](http://www.math.msu.edu/~shapiro/Teaching/classes/425/crpolar.pdf).)

Comment: Could you explain why the interval for the argument has open endpoints?

Comment: Simply to exclude the negative numbers (i.e. $\vartheta=\pi$).

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the negative numbers? Thanks

Comment: Basically excluding them, we exclude the whole line $(-\infty,1]$ for $g$.

Comment: Why do the branch cuts $(-\infty, -1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ ensure analyticity in the interior of the unit circle?

Comment: The $\sqrt{z}$ can not be defined as analytic in a neighborhood of $z=0$. But it can be defined in $\mathbb C$ excluding a line (or curve) starting from $0$ and going to infinity. (This is not totally trivial.) So excluding $(-\infty,1]$ we make indeed $\sqrt{z-1}$ analytic.

Comment: That case is a bit more complicated. I would use, for that case the following lemma: *If $a,b$ belong to same connected component of $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\Omega$, then $g(z)=\log\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)$ is analytic in $\Omega$.* Then $\sqrt{z^2-1}=(z+1)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)\right)$, where $1,-1\in [-1,1]$ and $\Omega=C\smallsetminus [-1,1]$.

Comment: Does my branch work though?

Comment: Yes you can use this branch.

Comment: I am fairly new to this topic, so could I just check that my notation/way of expressing the branch is correct?

Comment: Sure. By the way, I fixed my answer a little bit.

Comment: Many thanks, the concepts are becoming clearer. Just a couple more questions: I read somewhere that for complex $z$, $(z_1 z_2)^a \neq z_1^a z_2^a$ in general. So why can I apply $(z^2-1)^{1/2} = (z-1)^{1/2} (z+1)^{1/2}$?  Finally, is it correct to say that $f(z)$ is nowhere  analytic on the interior of disk of radius $2$ centered on the origin? (since this includes the branch point at $z=1$?

Answer (score 3):

If we make the branch cut along $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:|x|\ge1\}$ and define
$$
f(z)=\frac{\pi i}{2}+\frac12\int_0^z\left(\frac1{w-1}+\frac1{w+1}\right)\,\mathrm{d}w
$$
then $f$ is well-defined since we can't circle either singularity with the branch cut. Furthermore,
$$
\sqrt{z^2-1}=e^{f(z)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $$f(z)= \sqrt{z^2-1}$$

Then function has two branch points at $z,=1,z=-1$, So it can be extended to the whole complex plane except at two branch cuts chosen properly.

you can choose the branch cut at $z^2-1\geq 0$ os $z\geq 1 \text{  and  } z\leq -1$.

This is like defining the argument as a singly valued function by choosing

$$\text{arg}(z) \in (0,2\pi]$$

Hence we here are choosing the half line $z\geq 0$ to be the branch cut . Simiarily for the function

$$f(z)=z^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{\frac{1}{2} \text{Log}(z)}$$

Here we are choosing the principle logarithm so the function is the principle root and is analytic for $z \in \mathbb{C}/(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: We we want the function to be discontinuous across the branch cut $z \geq 1$, (so the resulting function is no longer multivalued), and so is that the reason why you choose one of the endpoints of $arg(z)$ to be open?

Comment: The values of $0$ and $2\pi$ coincides and to make the function singly valued we need to remove one of them.

Comment: Can you give any comments about my two questions above (in the comment section of the other users answer)? Thanks,

Comment: @CAF, can you restate your questions ?

Comment: Sure, in this question the first step was to express $(z^2-1)^{1/2} = (z-1)^{1/2} (z+1)^{1/2}$, however I read in my book that in general $(z_1 z_2)^{\alpha} \neq z_1^{\alpha} z_2^{\alpha}$. So why is the splitting valid?

Comment: I was also wondering if it was possible to say that $f(z)$ is not analytic on the interior of a disk of radius > $1$ centered on the origin since the branch point $z=1$ is contained within it?

Comment: @CAF , If we put $z_1 = r_1 e^{i \theta_1}$ and $z_2=r_2 e^{i \theta_2}$ then 

$$(z_1 \cdot z_2)^\alpha=(r_1r_2\,e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)})^\alpha=r_1^\alpha e^{i\alpha\theta_1} r_2^{\alpha} \, e^{i\alpha\theta_2}=z_1^\alpha z_2^\alpha$$

Comment: The circle $|z|=1$ is not included in the interior of $|z|\geq 1$.

Comment: So do you mean to say that $(z_1 z^2)^{\alpha} = z_1^{\alpha} z_2^{\alpha}$ in general. My book seems to say otherwise. I think I rephrased my second question wrong - what I meant was that if we consider a disk of radius $r>2$ centered on the origin, then $f(z)$ is not analytic on the interior of this disk since the branch points $-1$ and $1$ are included within this disk. And by definition, a function is not analytic at the branch points.

Comment: @CAf , yes, if you consider the interior of $|z|\leq 2$ then this cannot be analytic since any branch cut has to be included in the disk. In general we have to indent around branch points to make the function analytic.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you have any comments about my book saying that $(z_1 z_2)^{\alpha} \neq z_1^{\alpha} z_2^{\alpha}$ in general?

Comment: @CAF , http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/clog_11.pdf , see page 12 the last two equations.

Answer (score 0):

it s very simple if you use the graphics, so you use $z-1 =r_1e^{i\theta_1}$, and so $z+1 =r_2e^{i\theta_2}$, than the function become $f (z)=\sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i \frac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}}$, study the argument by using a graphics.

Comment: So the argument is $(\theta_1 + \theta_2)/2$.  This is the same as $(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2 + 2\pi k$ How does this help? Thanks.